# How to run a single java file which contains main inside in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I want to just compile and run a simple java file in IntelliJ, I already did these steps as others, who had this issues.

1. Setup the Project Structure to have the correct Content Root for Modules.
2. Setup the Run/Debug Configurations.

Here are the snapshots to my codes, my Project Structure and my Run/Debug Configurations
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the icon of the **Names.java** file. The icon has a letter J which is surronded by a red circle. This means your Java class is located outside of the source root. 
Refer to the links below to know more about the symbols used in intellij.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html

To solve the above problem,you will have to configure the content root. Go to File > project structure > Modules and set the Lab1 folder as the src root.

After correctly setting it, the icon will be a blue circle surrounding the letter C.

More info about content root configuration is here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you make your main class public.

```
public class Names {

    public static void main(String[] args) { }

}
```

that's what your class should look like.